# What is meant by "Component model"

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, terminology

I am reading EJB 3 in Action and they use the term "Component model" or "Component". What do they mean? What is the difference between a component model and a component?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Component model refers to the architecture where a system is build using components.

Component itself refers to a functional unit providing services by an interface (internal methods cannot be invoked due to encapsulation).